# number of loops of length $n$ without crossings in random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, reference-request, random-walk

Consider the symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$, where you go in one of the four directions with probability 1/4. We start in 0. My question is whether there are results on counting how many ways there are to do a random walk of $n$ steps and get back to the starting point without ever crossing a point where you have already been, except of course the starting point. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want sequence [A010566](http://oeis.org/A010566) at OEIS; there are many references.  There are *many* related sequences as well; the general search term you want is *self-avoiding [closed] random walk.*

Comment: Thanks for this information. A short question: do you think it is possible to have an exact expression for this sequence? Or are there any exact expression for asymptotics, i.e. the large $n$ limit?

Comment: I doubt there's an exact expression. The asymptotics are a very rich area; for example, see the now classic paper of Lawler, Schramm and Werner on conformal invariance of the scaled limit of loop-erased random walk (http://www.jstor.org/stable/3481623).